# Create a custom MediaPickerController

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaquery

I was tasked to create a music player application that is sort of like a DJ app, and when the add music button is clicked, it needs to show the list of all the songs just like the native `MediaPickerController` but with added functionalities like sorting, search and not fullscreen which is not available in the native one.

I tried scouring the internet for an answer but I can't find anything about this, it's all about creating the native media picker controller.

I found about **MPMediaQuery** which allows you to get the songs list in the phone, but I can't use it in a **for-in**

Sample:

```
MPMediaQuery *songs = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    for (MPMediaItem *item in songs) {

    }
```

But I get this:

***Collection expression type 'MPMediaQuery *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'***

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

About the mediaquery, you need to convert it to nsarray first, try this:

```
MPMediaQuery *songs = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray *songList = [songs items];
    for (MPMediaItem *item in songList) {

    }
```